# Looping a code a certain amount of times

Tags: python

This program randomly chooses a number between 2 and 7 and adds it to a loop program that i want to loop that amount of times. For example the random function randomly chooses 3 and i want the loop program to loop 3 times because of that random function.

```
import random

num = random.randint(2,7)
def program():
    print("Hello")

program()

while program() == (num):
    program()
```

please tell me if this is correct and can be done thanks.

Comment: Did you run it in your shell?

Comment: Yes i have but it only prints the "Hello" part twice, even if the program chooses 3 or higher.

Comment: Given that `program` returns `None`, why would `program()` ever `== (num)`?! Did you mean `for _ in range(num):`?

Comment: cause i edited it to show me the number it chose, sorry did not put that in.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try a while loop with a variable like counter:

```
i = 2;
while i <= num:
    program()
    i = i + 1
```

Here your random number will generate from 2 to 7. So define a counter variable with 2 and loop until your counter variable is less than or equal to randome number generated and go on calling your method and at the same time increment your counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is commented code to do what you're asking.

```
import random

# define the function you want to run
def program():
    print("Hello")

# run it a random amount of times (meaningful variable names is important!).
times = random.randint(2,7)
# underscore means we're not going to use the loop variable
for _ in xrange(times):
    program()
```